# Android app with images to point at for travelling

Tags: android, images, travel

When it first came out as a booklet, the 'travellers picture dictionary' [Point it](http://www.graf-editions.de/en/pointit) was lovely to work with.

It had pictures of common household items, foods, medicines, transportation, tools, sights, professions, anything you might be searching for/wanting in a foreign country that you don't speak the language of, together with some geographical maps. IIRC some 20-30 pages full of stuff.

[image]

They also made [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialbit.pointit), but it gets bad reviews (I e.g. agree with the complaint of the pictures having watermarks).

Does anyone know of an alternative?

- It does not have to be free (let's say up to US$10).
- I don't need texts or pronunciations.
- It has to work offline (no Internet connection)
- Lookup speed is essential, you don't want to have to fumble with your app for a minute to point out something. Their current app does that with an index like this, so that you are two clicks away from the photo:

[image]

Comment: While I usually recommend taking a look into the corresponding app listing of mine: I'd done that for vocabulary, but I don't have a list for this kind of app. Though some of the [Language Guides](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_languageguides) might have that (includes "travel helpers"), like [Travel Interpreter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.jourist.TravelInterpreterDemo).

Comment: Oh: [SameSame](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.samesame.android) could be your candidate!